# Can't access website with domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

I am using a VPS for the first time and could semi-published my website. I installed DNS and created A and NS records, installed IIS and uploaded my website. I edited domain panel to point the nameservers. The problem is, when I type ip to address bar, I can see the website. When I type domain, I get ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED error.

IP is: 192.211.51.30 and domain is: css3egitimseti.com

I am using Windows 2008 Server and don't have plesk or cpanel.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Properties for IPv4 was 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, I changed to my server ip. But when I try nslookup, I get

```
Server:google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8
```

Is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The child name servers that were provided to the registrar ns2.css3egitimseti.com. and ns1.css3egitimseti.com. does not have the DNS records for the domain.

Check the zone file at the name servers to make sure you have added the records correctly.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Can you send an article or tutorial?

Comment: This page should show you what's wrong with the name server configuration :     http://www.intodns.com/css3egitimseti.com

Comment: Ok but how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to create nameservers only for one domain on the same server. And that becomes a nameserver for whole domains in that server. My mistake was to create nameservers for each domain. I still couldn't succeed but at least one step is left behind.